# In what situations are slower sorting algorithms (bubble sort, selection sort, etc) more useful than faster algorithms such Quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting

I just wrote an essay about the efficiency and usefulness of different sorting algorithms. I concluded that merge sort and quicksort were far better when sorting completely randomized lists. I just wanted to ask in what situations would the slower sorting algorithms for this scenario (bubble sort and selection sort) be more useful or as useful as quicksort and merge sort.

Comment: Well Insertion sort is quite fast for almost sorted lists, same for shell sort

Comment: I think that in some implementations you switch from quicksort to insertion sort once the array becomes small because of the constant factors involved. See also this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37956/why-is-the-optimal-cut-off-for-switching-from-quicksort-to-insertion-sort-machin

Answer (score 0):

Notice that both merge sort and quicksort may require additional memory, whether this is heap space required to save the stack for recursion or actual copy of the buffer.

Bubble sort and selection sort does not require additional memory. So in situations where memory is a strict restriction they would be used.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion involved in quick sort or merge can be expensive when we are soting quite a few numers (may be less than 100)

In this case insertion sort performs much better.

Even the standard implementations of sorting libraries in Java uses a mix of quick-merge and insertion sort

HTH

Comment: Did you actually measure this? I did when I was young and curious :-) Bubblesort in handwritten highly optimised assembler code lost against absolutely straightforward non-optimised Quicksort for n = 64.

Answer (score 0):

There are *stable* sorting algorithms which keep items that compare equal arranged in the original order. If this is important to you, then you would use a stable sorting algorithm even if slower.

There are some cases where simpler algorithms are *faster* (because obviously a slower algorithm is never more useful if it doesn't have other advantages).

I have seen one situation where an array was sorted, and then each array element was modified by a tiny amount. So most items were in the right position, and only a few needed exchanging. In that case shakersort proved optimal.

If you know that the array was sorted, and then a small number of items was changed, there is a clever algorithm for that (which you find somewhere on cs.stackexchange.com): If k items have been changed, you can extract at most 2k items into a separate array, sort that (using Quicksort most likely) and merge the two arrays.

If you use a library function, it is unlikely to be plain Quicksort. For example, Apple's implementation looks for a sorted range at the beginning and the end of the array, and if there are substantial numbers of items already sorted, takes advantage of this (for example sorting the concatenation of two sorted arrays runs in linear time).